# Unable to install Virtualmin

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, virtualmin

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

I want to install Virtualmin on my VPS, but I am getting errors while installating. Check the below errors:

```
INFO - Removing Debian standard Webmin package, if they exist...
INFO - Removing Debian apache packages...
INFO - Installing dependencies using command: /usr/bin/apt-get --config-file apt.conf.noninteractive -y --force-yes install bsdutils postfix postfix-pcre webmin usermin ruby libxml-simple-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl unzip zip libfcgi-dev bind9 spamassassin spamc procmail procmail-wrapper libnet-ssleay-perl libpg-perl libdbd-pg-perl libdbd-mysql-perl quota iptables openssl python mailman subversion ruby irb rdoc ri mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common postgresql postgresql-client awstats webalizer dovecot-common dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d proftpd libcrypt-ssleay-perl awstats clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav clamav-freshclam clamav-docs clamav-testfiles libapache2-mod-fcgid apache2-suexec-custom scponly apache2 apache2-doc libapache2-svn libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules sasl2-bin php-pear php5 php5-cgi libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
...in progress, please wait...
.E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

/usr/bin/apt-get --config-file apt.conf.noninteractive -y --force-yes install bsdutils postfix postfix-pcre webmin usermin ruby libxml-simple-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl unzip zip libfcgi-dev bind9 spamassassin spamc procmail procmail-wrapper libnet-ssleay-perl libpg-perl libdbd-pg-perl libdbd-mysql-perl quota iptables openssl python mailman subversion ruby irb rdoc ri mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common postgresql postgresql-client awstats webalizer dovecot-common dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d proftpd libcrypt-ssleay-perl awstats clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav clamav-freshclam clamav-docs clamav-testfiles libapache2-mod-fcgid apache2-suexec-custom scponly apache2 apache2-doc libapache2-svn libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules sasl2-bin php-pear php5 php5-cgi libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql failed.  Error (if any): 0

Displaying the last 15 lines of /root/virtualmin-install.log to help troubleshoot this problem:
sasl2-bin is already the newest version.
unzip is already the newest version.
php5 is already the newest version.
php5-cgi is already the newest version.
php5-cgi set to manually installed.
php-pear is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-fcgid : Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed
 libapache2-svn : Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed

FATAL - Fatal Error Occurred: Something went wrong during installation: 0
FATAL - Cannot continue installation.
FATAL - Attempting to remove virtualmin repository configuration, so the installation can be
FATAL - re-attempted after any problems have been resolved.
FATAL - Removing temporary directory and files.
FATAL - If you are unsure of what went wrong, you may wish to review the log
FATAL - in /root/virtualmin-install.log
```

I have also tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get -f install`.
I have removed Apache but no success.
Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: It's possible that you added a PPA, that installs some software which in turn requires some dependencies not provided by any of your existing repositories... Check the answers in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: nothing helped me i tried every thing which was in your post.
Whenever i am going to install any open source control panel i get these errors.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-fcgid : Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Having the same issue it seems, but came across this: https://www.virtualmin.com/node/37048 It may be an ongoing issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)